# Insert Data to MYSQL using Foxpro

Tags: mysql, insert, foxpro

In FoxPro using native table, I usually do this when inserting new Data.

```
Sele Table
If Seek(lcIndex)
     Update Record
Else
     Insert New Record
EndIf
```

If I will use MYSQL as my DataBase, what is the best and fastest way to
do this in FoxPro code using SPT? I will be updating a large number of records.
Up to 80,000 transactions.

Thanks,
Herbert

Answer (score 1):

I would only take what Jerry supplied one step further.  When trying to deal with any insert, update, delete with SQL pass through, it can run into terrible debugging problems based on similar principles of SQL-injection.

What if your "myValue" field had a single quote, double quote, double hyphen (indicating comment)?  You would be hosed.

Parameterize your statement such as using VFP variable references, then use "?" in your sql statement to qualify which "value" should be used.  VFP properly passes.  This also helps on data types, such as converting numbers into string when building the "myStatement".

Also, in VFP, you can use TEXT/ENDTEXT to simplify the readability of the commands

```
lcSomeStringVariable = "My Test Value"
lnANumericValue = 12.34
lnMyIDKey = 389


TEXT to lcSQLCmd NOSHOW PRETEXT 1+2+8
   update [YourSchems].[YourTable]
      set SomeTextField = ?lcSomeStringVariable,
          SomeNumberField = ?lnANumericValue
      where
          YourPKColumn = ?lnMyIDKey
ENDTEXT

=sqlexec( yourHandle, lcSQLCmd, "localCursor" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Pass through in your Visual Foxpro application. Take a look at the SQLCONNECT() or SQLSTRINGCONNECT() for connecting to your Database. Also look at SQLEXEC() for executing your SQL statement.

For Example:

```
myValue = 'Test'
myHandle = SQLCONNECT('sqlDBAddress','MyUserId','MyPassword')
myStatement = "UPDATE [MySchema].[Mytable] SET myField = '" + myValue + "' WHERE myPk = 1"
=SQLEXEC(myHandle, myStatement,"myCursor")
=SQLEXEC(myHandle, "SELECT * FROM [MySchema].[Mytable] WHERE myPk = 1","myCursor")
SELECT myCursor
BROWSE LAST NORMAL
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be your statement string for SQLEXEC:

```
INSERT INTO SOMETABLE 
SET KEYFIELD = ?M.KEYFIELD, 
FIELD1 = ?M.FIELD1
...
FIELDN = ?M.FIELDN
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
FIELD1 = ?M.FIELD1
...
FIELDN = ?M.FIELDN
```

Notice that the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE part does not contain the key field, otherwise it would normally be identical to the insert (or not, if you want to do something else when the record already exists)